# MSSQL Server permissions + Entity Framework [Необходимые разрешения]

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Ранее имел дело с MySQL сервером и понятной установкой разрешений для аккаунтов и объектов. 
Сейчас разбираюсь с MSSQL сервером и Entity Framework.
Я создал имя входа *(логин, пароль)*, прикрепил пользователя бд к этому имени и создал схему (владелец dbo/sa). 
Ещё не успел изучить все аспекты внутренней работы MSSQL сервера да и это не является основной целью.

**Вопрос**: Какие минимальные разрешения нужно указать в схеме для этого логина, чтобы EF могла полноценно функционировать (CRUD и прочие типичные задачи и внутренние процессы) не трогая другие БД (в общем чтобы не беспокоиться о безопасности)

Возможно я упускаю ещё некоторые важные моменты. Буду рад сопутствующим советам!

Comment: Давно не лазал туда, но там вроде есть роли для юзера или логинадля конкретной БД, что то типа db_owner - чтобы получить полный доступ к БД. Но это не точно :)

Comment: @tym32167 верно, можно добавить юзеру роль db_owner, но я так понимаю что это даст полный контроль над конкретной базой. Я бы хотел обратного эффекта, минимально необходимый доступ для работы EF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF - это просто способ построения запросов к базе.

Минимально необходимый доступ зависит от того, что именно вы собираетесь через EF делать. "Полноценно" - очень нечеткое определение. Обычно под "полноценно" подразумевается "..включая миграции". В миграциях вы можете написать какой угодно код. Поэтому для "полноценной работы" в общем случае вам придется выдать db_owner.

Но можно закрутить гайки.

Если вам нужно только выбирать данные - db_datareader. Если еще и менять - db_datawriter. Если вызывать хранимки - выдайте права на конкретные хранимки. Если хотите строгого контроля - выставляйте права на каждую таблицу и каждую колонку. Если хотите менять схему (миграциями) - ddl_admin. Если *<что-то еще>* - выдайте права на это *что-то еще*.

Т.е. настройка прав для EF ничем не отличается для настройки прав для любого другого клиентского кода и любого другого клиентского приложения.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что фраза ```настройка прав для EF``` в принципе не имеет смысла. Есть права юзера, который используется для подключения к бд.

Comment: @tym32167 примерно это и сказано в моем ответе, только более развернуто :)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Попробую ещё раз в двух словах: Я слышал что EF каким-то образом следит за вытянутыми сущностями во время работы с ними (например другая транзакция частично изменила данные). Каким образом это сделано со стороны ORM / MSSQL я не знаю, по сему и хотел узнать о таких подводных камнях и их зависимостях в виде разрешений. Понятно что можно написать какой-угодно SQL код затрагивающий чужие базы и объекты, но в вопросе имелось ввиду именно типичное использование этого конкретного ORM фреймворка (миграции, crud, слежение?).

Comment: @tym32167 Оно понятно что права выдаются пользователю, через которого работает EF составляя SQL из моего C# кода. Вопрос именно в связке разрешений необходимых для этого кода. Ну и возможно подсказки каким именно образом этого лучше/правильнее достичь.

Comment: @Новичок слежение работает на уровне .NET, за счет сравнения объектов, выбранных через контекст, с их реальными значениями. с точки зрения SQL Server - EF делает обычные CRUD